# How to check for consecutive values in a table?

Tags: lua

When checking for consecutive values in my table, my current code just counts the length of the table - however, when counting non-consecutive values, it works perfectly.

My attempt can be seen in the code below; the top code is the non-consecutive count, which works - the bottom code is my attempted, and failed, consecutive count code.

```lua
--creates a function that counts the number of things in a table
function tCount(t,str,con)
    if con ~= true then
        local count = 0
        for _,v in pairs(t) do --key/value of table
            if v == str then --if values matches the string
                count = count + 1 --add 1 to count
            end
        end
        return count
    else --consecutive count code
        local cCount = 0
        for k,v in pairs(t) do --key/value of table
            if k == 1 then --if it's the first index
                if v == str then --if the value is equal to the inputted string
                    cCount = cCount + 1 --add 1 to consecutiveCount
                end
            else
                if v[k] == v[k-1] then --if the value is equal to the previous value
                    cCount = cCount + 1 --add 1 to consecutiveCount
                else --otherwise
                    cCount = 1 --set consecutiveCount back to 1
                end
            end
        end
        return cCount --return the consecutiveCount value
    end 
end

--debug
alpha = {"one","one","three","one","two"}
print(tCount(alpha,"one",false),tCount(alpha,"one",true))
```

`Result:    3    5`

I'd like it to restart the count every time a new value appears, and currently it just counts every value.

What did I do wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`v` is a string. `v[k]` and `v[k-1]` are both `nil`. Hence your condition to increment `cCount` is always `true`.

`t[k] == t[k-1]` or simply `v == t[k-1]` would be correct.

In order to debug things like that ask yourself: why is my count too high?
Because I increment too often.
Why do I increment to often? This is only possible if my condition is true too often. So let's see what is going on and print v[k] and v[k-1] every time. Ok both values are nil every time. Why?...